# how to exclude leads and contacts that were in a previous campaign

Tags: reporting, campaign, campaign-member

This is not an automation or coding question.

This is a procedural question, i.e., "how to". I have researched through functionality, documentation and support questions/answeres and yet found no solution.

I have 4000 leads and contacts. I have run three previous campaigns, each campaign was a combination of leads and contacts, some leads and contacts were in more than one campaign. I now want to select a certain sector of leads and contacts (I can do this by identifying various field values for the records) that are NOT included in any of the previous campaigns or perhaps just one of the previous campaigns. How can I dot this?

Comment: Personally, I'd probably code something up with Apex to build up sets of lead and contact Ids, and then use those to create the Campaign Members in the target Campaign. It sounds like you don't won't to use Apex though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Enterprise Edition, you can use [cross filters](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_cross_filters_create.htm&language=en_US) to add a "Without" filter on the Campaign History object for both Leads and Contacts, and then add those folks to your new campaign.

There is also a free app, [Campaign Combiner](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IlDHEA0) that will create new campaigns based on the presence or absence of campaign membership in other campaigns.